# WPF MVVM View with lookup or join to other entities

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, mvvm

I am getting started with WPF and MVVM.  I am just reading up on [Code Project Article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36545/WPF-MVVM-Model-View-View-Model-Simplified) which is quite interesting and provides a good quick start.  I am using Entity Framework and I am happy I have listed all of my entities in a ListView.

I am curious how you would correctly implement lookups - in the view model or create a new model.  Take the simple case of a person.  The data structure might be:

```
public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
    public Toy FaveToy { get; set; }
}

public class Toy
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Model { get; set; }
    public string Manufacturer { get; set; }
}
```

I want my list view to show the columns FirstName, LastName, DateOfBirth, Fave Toy, Manufacturer.

The Toy field will be a combined string with Name + " " + Model in.

So given some of the code in the example I've linked (I've knocked the Person class up for examples sake):

**Base Class for the views**

```
public abstract class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;

        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

**My implementation for the Person view**

```
public class PersonViewModel : ViewModelBase 
{
    private ObservableCollection<Person> _Person;

    public PersonViewModel()
    {
        _Person = new ObservableCollection<Person>();

        Entities context = new Entities();

        foreach(var person in context.Person.ToList())
        {
            _Person.Add(person);
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Person> Person
    {
        get
        {
            return _Person;
        }
        set
        {
            _Person = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged("Person");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Bind your ListView to Persons property, bind Fave Toy column to FaveToy.Name and bind Manufacturer to FaveToy.Manufacturer

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding correct you want to access a Toy through the FaveToy property automatically.

Normally this would be done creating a relation between Person and Toy.  Once you've done so your Person entity type would look like this:

```
public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
    public virtual Toy FaveToy { get; set; }
}
```

Notice the "virtual" on FaveToy.  This indicates a navigation property which would be accessible through *person instance*.FaveToy.  This can be represented in XAML either through dot notation or using the path property on your binding.  Here is a link that discusses navigation properties: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj713564.aspx

If you want to represent the toy by a combination of name and model then a converter would do the trick on the binding.  Here is a link that discusses converters http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.aspx

Hope this helps...Jason

PS - Josh Smith is awesome in his discussion of WPF and MVVM http://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/a-guided-tour-of-wpf/

If you're a VB guy  Alessandro has trhe best discussion for VB that I've seen:  http://community.visual-basic.it/Alessandroenglish/archive/2010/08/13/31861.aspx

PSS -- WPF and MVVM (or Windows 8 and XAML) are awesome.  Definitely worth your time to pick up.

Comment: Thanks for the info Jason...  Will check it out over the weekend.